# android service not returning to calling activity after StopSelf

Tags: android, service, location

I've an activity that calls a service that has an inner class that implements a locationListener. The service is designed to get the user's location. Once it has found the location it sets the lon/lat values in an application object from which the calling activity can retrieve them. In onLocationChanged, once i have the lon/lat values and set them i call Service.StopSelf. The service does stop according to the loggings but doesn't return to the calling activity. At this point in the calling activity i try to get those values from the application object to further process them. No code is being executed after startService in the calling activity. Any ideas why. thanks in advance.

[edit]
The values are being set in the app object

In the calling activity.

```
startService(new Intent(NfcscannerActivity.this, LocationService.class));


                double latitude = nfcscannerapplication.getLat();
                double longitude = nfcscannerapplication.getLon();

                Log.e(TAG, "got the geopoint from application object...." + latitude + " " + longitude);
```

The service.

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LocationService extends Service{

    private static final String TAG = LocationService.class.getSimpleName();
    LocationManager mlocManager;
    LocationListener mlocListener;
    NfcScannerApplication nfcscannerapplication;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        nfcscannerapplication = (NfcScannerApplication)getApplication();
        mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);   
        mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();

        Log.e(TAG, "Service created and location manager and listener created");
        super.onCreate();
    }



    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
         mlocManager.removeUpdates(mlocListener);
         Log.e(TAG, "Service destroyed");
        super.onDestroy();
    }




    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
         Log.e(TAG, "requesting location updates");
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
    }



    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }







    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
    {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
            Log.e(TAG, "about to set geopoints in application object");
            nfcscannerapplication.setLat( loc.getLatitude());
            nfcscannerapplication.setLon(loc.getLongitude()); 
            String Text = "My current location is: " +"Latitude = " + loc.getLatitude() + "Longitude = " 
            + loc.getLongitude();             
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), Text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            LocationService.this.stopSelf();




        }



        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


    }//end of MyLocationListener





}// end of service
```

The Application object.

```
public class NfcScannerApplication extends Application{

    private static final String TAG = NfcScannerApplication.class.getSimpleName();
    LoginValidate loginValidate;
    ValidateUser validateUser;
    LoginWebservice loginWebservice;
    DateTime globalDateTime;
    double lon;
    public double getLon() {
        return lon;
    }

    public void setLon(double lon) {
        Log.e(TAG, "inside setLon in app obj");
        this.lon = lon;
    }

    public double getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(double lat) {
        Log.e(TAG, "inside setLat in app obj");
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    double lat;
```

Comment: You will have the lon et lal all time equal to 0; You must call a callback when your lon/lal change, to be able to get the last retrieved location. you can create a Braoscast from your service before stopping it.

Comment: @Anis i do use the callback onLocationChanged and the lon and lat values are set in the application object ready for retrieval, as i've just logged the values out. i just need to know how to make the service stop itself, everything else works

Comment: @Anis Actually sorry i have just checked the logging correctly and you are correct the lon/lat values are set to 0. Could you explain the Broadcast ideas please

Comment: The broadcast is used to fire the Location change event to your activity. I will update an answer. But the service will stop if you receive the update.

Comment: @Anis Thanks, yes that is ok i just want the service to get the geopoints and pass them back to the activity, then the service should stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Create a Custom Intent Object to hold your location data:

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.example.test;

import android.content.Intent;

/**
 * @author formation1
 * 
 */
public class LocationChangeIntent extends Intent {
    private final double       lon;
    private final double       lal;

    public static final String ACTION_LOCATION_CHAHGE = "com.example.test.LocationChangeIntent";

    /**
     * @param aLon
     * @param aLal
     */
    public LocationChangeIntent(double aLon, double aLal) {
        super(ACTION_LOCATION_CHAHGE);
        lon = aLon;
        lal = aLal;
    }

    /**
     * @return the lal
     */
    public double getLaltitude() {
        return lal;
    }

    /**
     * @return the lon
     */
    public double getLongitude() {
        return lon;
    }

}
```

---

After that you have to add sendBroadcast from the service:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class LocationService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = LocationService.class.getSimpleName();
    LocationManager             mlocManager;
    LocationListener            mlocListener;
    NfcScannerApplication       nfcscannerapplication;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        nfcscannerapplication = (NfcScannerApplication) getApplication();
        mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();

        Log.e(TAG, "Service created and location manager and listener created");
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mlocManager.removeUpdates(mlocListener);
        Log.e(TAG, "Service destroyed");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
        Log.e(TAG, "requesting location updates");
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
            Log.e(TAG, "about to set geopoints in application object");
            nfcscannerapplication.setLat(loc.getLatitude());
            nfcscannerapplication.setLon(loc.getLongitude());
            String text = "My current location is: " + "Latitude = " + loc.getLatitude() + "Longitude = "
                + loc.getLongitude();
            Log.d(TAG, text);
            fireLocationChangeEvent(loc.getLongitude(), loc.getLatitude());

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }// end of MyLocationListener

    private void fireLocationChangeEvent(double lon, double lal) {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(new LocationChangeIntent(lon, lal));
    }
}// end of service
```

---

Finally register aBrodcast receiver from your Activity.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private BroadcastReceiver   locationChangereceiver;
    private double              lon;
    private double              lal;

    TextView                    text;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

        locationChangereceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                LocationChangeIntent myIntent = (LocationChangeIntent) intent;
                lon = myIntent.getLongitude();
                lal = myIntent.getLaltitude();
                text.setText(String.format("Location Update/Read from Activity\n  long : %s lalt:  %s ", lon, lal));
                // stop the service.
                stopService(new Intent(context, LocationService.class));
            }
        };
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).registerReceiver(locationChangereceiver,
                new IntentFilter(LocationChangeIntent.ACTION_LOCATION_CHAHGE));
        startService(new Intent(this, LocationService.class));

        // Log.e(TAG, "got the geopoint from application object...." + latitude
        // + " " + longitude);

    }

    /**
     * callback method from QuantityDialogFragment, returning the value of user
     * input.
     * 
     * @param selectedValue
     */
    public void onUserSelectValue(String selectedValue) {

        // TODO add your implementation.
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onDestroy()
     */
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
        // if no update make sure to stop the servcie.
        stopService(new Intent(this, LocationService.class));
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).unregisterReceiver(locationChangereceiver);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to put this together, but i think there maybe a few problems with integrating it into my code. Firstly i can't resolve LocalBroadcastManager. Also my activity doesnot extend fragmentActivity, it just extends Activity.

Comment: imported everything and it works a treat. Thankyou very much for you time and help, it's appreciated.

Comment: what is your sdk target ? if 2.2 you must add the Compatibility library.

Comment: 4.0. but i've added the necessary stuff and runs well. It this the only way to do it using LocalBroadcastManager and custom intent objects?

Comment: No you can register Listener on the Service, or just remove all you update location listener code to your activity. With brodcast you will not have to manage Listener and you can receive update event from any other activity or service...

Comment: ok thanks can i ask just one more question about the code you have given me? Is the service Asynchonous? The problem is the code in my activity seems to finsh executing before the results of the service come back. How can i get the activity to wait until the service results come back?

Comment: change you stuff code to the onReceive() method of the BroadcastReceiver. The services is being finished from your activity.

Comment: Hi Anis sorry for contacting you on this thread but I'm following this tutorial http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-proximity-alerts-tutorial.html I'm struggling to make this work in the service you gave me yesterday. I'd like to add a proximity sensor to the code. Have you an idea how i could extract what i need to do this from the tutorial. or indeed if you have a easier way you wouldn't mind sharing? I can start a different thread if you'd like to answer on it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17499/discussion-between-anis-and-turtleboy)